# regex for insensitive proceeding alphabets

Tags: regex, alphabet

I want to have a regex match alphabets with its minimum at abc.

So I want to detect if the string contains the alphabet (abcdefghijk...) with case insensitivity.

So it could match :

```
abc
AbC
abcde
ABCDE
abCdefG
```

But not match :

```
cdef  -- missing the a
abd   -- missing the c
```

How could i do this?

Comment: Please label with the regex tool/language you are using.

Comment: With `proceeding alphabets` do you mean that `abcdez` should not match because of the `z`?

Comment: For "a" to "g" in javascript: `/\ba(?=b|\b)b?(?=c|\b)c?(?=d|\b)d?(?=e|\b)e?(?=f|\b)f?(?=g|\b)g?(?=h|\b)\b/gi`.  But if you would extend that for the whole alphabet it becomes a monstrosity of a regex. A simple loop in your programming language to check each character of a string that matches `/^a[b-z]+$/i`could turn out to be a better golf.